# I want to update a single record in SQL Server 2016 with 2000+ concurrent request with less duration

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016, I have a table `table1` with 2 columns `name` and `value`. Basically it's like a counter - every time I will update with increment of one for every request.

And the query I am using for the update is:

```
DECLARE @counter INT; 
SET @counter = '124';        

UPDATE table1 
SET Value = @counter 
WHERE Name = 'requestCount'
```

When I am running with 2000+ concurrent requests, it's getting slower response, on average the duration is 3476 ms.

Requirement: average duration shold be less than 100 ms. Is this possible? if yes how can we achieve this?

Thank in advance

Comment: What **datatype** is the `Name` column - and is it indexed? How many entries are there in the `table1` table?

Comment: To increment the value, using `set value = value + 1` would be better as it will result in correct increments. If you do the increment on the client, this might be incorrect - but it won't change the performance.

Comment: datatype of Name column : varchar(30); total of 7 records in that table

Comment: And is there an **index** on the `Name` column?

Comment: yes it is indexed

Comment: **Side note**: if you're initializing an  `INT` variable, you should **really NOT** use single quotes! Use this: `DECLARE @counter INT = 124;`. Adding single quotes just makes it a string literal, and SQL Server has to silently convert it back to an `INT` - useless work....

Comment: @marc_s:in real time i get this value from other table which is same data type. individually above query taking negligible time but when running concurrently more number of users duration increasing can u explain where it is delaying?